# Store the same string in two different struct types

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct, char

I'm working on structures, and I need to assign a string in a char array. Here is my some spesific parts of my code:

```
typedef struct{
    int std_id;
    char std_name[STD_NAME_SIZE];
    double gpa;
    char courses[COURSE_SIZE];
}student_t;

typedef struct{
    int course_id;
    char course_name[COURSE_NAME_SIZE];
    char course_code[COURSE_CODE_SIZE];
    char course_acronym[COURSE_ACRONYM_SIZE];
    int quota;
}course_t;
```

this is the struct that I use.
and this is the assignment part:

```
for(int i = 0; i < COURSE_SIZE; i++){
        printf("Enter course name: ");
        scanf("%s", &courseDetails.course_name);
        studentProfile.courses[i] = courseDetails.course_name;

    }

    for(int j = 0; j < COURSE_SIZE; j++){
        printf("\nYour %d course is: %s", j + 1, studentProfile.courses[j]);
    }
```

I think the problem happens at `studentProfile.courses[i] = courseDetails.course_name` part.
Should I use pointers? How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: It looks like there could be more to the puzzle. The problem that I see right away is `char courses[COURSE_SIZE];` This is an array of characters but you are assigning arrays of characters to each value. I suspect you need to change that line to an array of character pointers. `char *courses[COURSE_SIZE];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the `courses` field an array of pointers to `char`. Also, `courseDetails` needs to be an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STD_NAME_SIZE       81
#define COURSE_SIZE         3
#define COURSE_NAME_SIZE    81
#define COURSE_CODE_SIZE    81
#define COURSE_ACRONYM_SIZE 81

typedef struct {
    int     std_id;
    char    std_name[STD_NAME_SIZE];
    double  gpa;
    char    *courses[COURSE_SIZE]; // Make this an array of pointers
} student_t;

typedef struct{
    int     course_id;
    char    course_name[COURSE_NAME_SIZE];
    char    course_code[COURSE_CODE_SIZE];
    char    course_acronym[COURSE_ACRONYM_SIZE];
    int     quota;
} course_t;

int main(void)
{
    student_t   studentProfile;
    course_t    courseDetails[COURSE_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < COURSE_SIZE; i++){
        printf("Enter course name: ");
        scanf("%s", courseDetails[i].course_name);
        studentProfile.courses[i] = courseDetails[i].course_name;
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < COURSE_SIZE; j++){
        printf("Your %d course is: %s\n", j + 1, studentProfile.courses[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Compiled With**

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -o scratch scratch.c
```

**Example Input and Output**

```
Enter course name: first
Enter course name: second
Enter course name: third

Your 1 course is: first
Your 2 course is: second
Your 3 course is: third
```

**Note**

This approach is very fragile because the string pointers in `studentProfile` point to strings stored in other variables. I understand that this is a toy program that is part of some kind of programming homework. However, I just want to caution anyone against using this code in a production environment. In a real program, you would probably just store an array of `course_id` values in the `student_t`. To get the course name, you would first find the `course_t` with the matching `course_id` and then display the `course_name`.

Comment: Thank you sir! that was really helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, COURSE_SIZE is defined as the maximum number of courses that a student can take. Then in the student_t struct, `courses` would be declared as `char courses[COURSE_SIZE][COURSE_NAME_SIZE]` and it would be set as
`strcpy(studentProfile.courses[i], courseDetails.course_name);`
But that is still not the correct way to do it. What you really want is the `courses` array to be an array of courses:

```
course_t *courses[COURSE_SIZE];
```

and set courses[i] to point to some course j:

```
studentProfile.courses[i] = &courseDetails[j];
```

then if you want to refer to the name of the ith course taken by that student you would use `courses[i]->course_name`.

Note that you will have to declare the course_t struct before you declare the student_t struct.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using not using pointers, you should use something like

```c
strcpy(studentProfile.courses[i], courseDetails.course_name);
```

EDIT:
this is obviously wrong, as comment points out.

maybe you just forgot array access for the other variable, as in

```c
courseDetails.course_name[i]
```

Comment: No. courses[i] is declared as a single char, not an array of char.

Comment: @FredK then how do you expect to copy a string in a single char? just change the single char to an array and use strcpy. that's it.